# How do I find out *why* a user has certain effective permissions?

Tags: sql-server, security, permissions, debugging

I know that I can query effective permissions by using [`sys.fn_my_permissions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx):

```
USE myDatabase;
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('dbo.myTable', 'OBJECT') 

 entity_name | subentity_name | permission_name 
------------------------------------------------
 dbo.myTable |                | SELECT          
 dbo.myTable |                | UPDATE          
 ...
```

This tells me whether the current user has SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, etc. permissions on `myTable` in database `myDatabase`.

Is it possible to easily find out *why* the user has these permissions? For example, I'd love to have a function `fn_my_permissions_ex` which outputs an additional `reason` column:

```
USE myDatabase;
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions_ex('dbo.myTable', 'OBJECT') 

 entity_name | subentity_name | permission_name | reason
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 dbo.myTable |                | SELECT          | granted to database role public
 dbo.myTable |                | UPDATE          | member of group MYDOMAIN\Superusers, which belongs to database role db_datawriter
 ...
```

Unfortunately, I could not find such a function in the SQL Server documentation. Is there a tool or script that provides this functionality?

Comment: why don't you export it into a txt file?, what OS are you using?

Comment: @jcho360: There is no function `fn_my_permission_ex`, so there's nothing that I could export. I'm asking if there is a function or tool with that *functionality*.

Comment: are you using SSMS?

Comment: Awesome question. I've been trying to figure this out for a very very long time. fn_my_permissions kinda works but often shows permissions that I cannot track down to an origin.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find some good information regarding security from the article below.

Reviewing SQL Server Permissions | TechRepublic http://tek.io/KfzEyp

Except:

> The following query uses the sys.database_permissions system view to
>   indicate which users had specific permissions inside the current
>   database.

```
SELECT
        dp.class_desc
       ,dp.permission_name
       ,dp.state_desc
       ,ObjectName = OBJECT_NAME(major_id)
       ,GranteeName = grantee.name
       ,GrantorName = grantor.name
    FROM
        sys.database_permissions dp
        JOIN sys.database_principals grantee
        ON dp.grantee_principal_id = grantee.principal_id
        JOIN sys.database_principals grantor
        ON dp.grantor_principal_id = grantor.principal_id
```